# ExtJS 5 grid editionn

Tags: extjs, grid

I try to prepare a simple grid with only two columns for edition (last two on the right: `number` and `checkbox`) . Edition by `CellEditing` plugin.

Grid is looking like this:

[image]

header of grid definition is:

```
{
       xtype: 'gridpanel',
       store: 'TimeStore',
       border: true,
       width: 800,
       cls: 'm-grid',
       margin: '10 0 0 0',
       selType: 'cellmodel',
       plugins: [
           Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
               clicksToEdit: 1,
               ptype: 'cellediting',
               listeners: {
                   'edit': function(edytor, data, event) {
                       ...
                       data.grid.view.refresh();
                       data.grid.getStore().commitChanges();
                   }
               }
           })
       ],
       features: [{
           ftype: 'summary'
       }],
       columns: [{..
       }]
   }
```

CSS definition:

```
.m-grid .x-grid-cell-selected{
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

And the two columns definition is like that:

```
{
    align: 'center',
    width: 80,
    dataIndex: 'F_NUM',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        allowBlank: false,
        maskRe: /[0-9,]/
    },
    renderer: function(value, meta) {
        meta.style = "background-color:lightgray;";
        return value;
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    align: 'center',
    width: 80,
    dataIndex: 'F_CHCK',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'checkboxfield'
    }
}
```

And this numeric field is working properly as expected but I have no idea what's wrong with the last column. Edition of this checkbox column can't work properly (when I check it and go to other place checked position become unchecked) and in addition I can't set the same background as I set for column with numbers (this light gray background color).

I try to use style:

```
renderer: function(value, meta) {
    meta.style = "background-color:lightgray;";
}
```

but result is the following:

[image]

And I can't find what's wrong in this code, could you help?

Comment: `checkcolumn` is a special column type that is already editable without an editor.

Comment: clear but I checked it, when I remove "editor" property from column definition situation is the same, can switch off check box but can't switch on and can't change background color

Comment: after a while - problem was with value (boolean and int), in my case this value in the model was int type, so I add convert function:               "convert: function (v, record) {
                       return typeof v === 'boolean' ? (v === true ? 1 : 0) : v;
                   }  }" and now I can switch on/off this field but background color is still puzzle